# Code to SpeedUp the MouseOver Effect

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If X < 1 Or X > Label1.Width - 1 Or Y < 1 Or Y > Label1.Height - 1 Then
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Menu2")).Visible = msoFalse
   Else
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Menu2")).Visible = msoTrue
End If

End Sub
```

This code show the shape named Menu2. I am facing a issue that when i move the mouse in speed, the Menu2 shape remains there. Is there any way to speed it up?

Thanks.
Salman

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `MouseMove` event triggers only within few pixels around the control (the lowest I got for X and Y is -3.75). The easiest alternative I could think of is to make a big transparent label behind it and use it's `MouseMove` event. Initial properties setup for the second label:

```
Label2.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
Label2.Visible = False
Label2.Caption = ""
```

and then (`Me` is the Worksheet where the controls are):

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Me.Shapes("Menu2").Visible = True
    Me.Label2.Visible = True                  ' optional so the Label2_MouseMove event triggers
    Me.Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow  ' optional to avoid the xlWait cursor flickering
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Me.Shapes("Menu2").Visible = False
    Me.Label2.Visible = False          ' optional so the Label2_MouseMove event doesn't trigger after the first time
    Me.Application.Cursor = xlDefault  ' optional to restore the cursor
End Sub
```

Another approach can be to use `GetCursorPos` WinAPI - [MouseMove - What is the reverse event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200618/mousemove-what-is-the-reverse-event)